# ASP.NET API consumes more memory on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, ubuntu, asp.net-web-api, memory

I have an ASP.NET Core API app that I need to publish on my production server which is run on Ubuntu.
When publish the app and run it on MS Windows it takes a reasonable amount of memory.

[image]

When I move the app to my production server `htop` shows that it takes a significant amount of memory compared to Windows.

[image]

So why is this happening?
Another question as well: Why is there more than one OS process running the same app?

Comment: Both OS have different ways of handling memory management. Linux tends to use more memory because it actively caches many system operations, which can make it appear that it is using more memory. To investigate further, you could try: Compare the runtime and SDK versions on both systems. Check the app's configurations for environment-specific settings. Look at the garbage collection logs to understand how memory is being managed. Inspect the processes to see if they are indeed all from your app or if they are system processes that are unrelated but appear related due to their resource usage.

Comment: Regarding why more than one OS process running the same app, it could be due to: If your application is designed to handle requests concurrently, it may spawn multiple processes to handle the load. This is a common feature in web servers to utilize multi-core processors more effectively.There might be background services or tasks that are part of your app that run as separate processes.Some libraries or components your app uses may start their own sub-processes for specific tasks. If the app was not shut down cleanly, it could have left orphaned processes that were not cleaned up properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the version of the .NET I was using: .NET 7.0.
See [Huge memory usage regression in dotnet 7 on linux](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/79633) Github issue.

For the OS processes running the same app:

> Threads: Implemented by the kernel as processes. That is, there are no dedicated data structures representing threads. Rather, a thread is a process that shares certain resources (such as memory or signal handlers) with other processes. The kernel identifies a thread via thread IDs (TID) and thread group IDs (TGID), with the semantics that a shared TGID value means a multithreaded process (in user land; there are also kernel threads, but that’s beyond our scope). [Hausenblas, Michael. *Learning Modern Linux*. Ch. 02.]

Answer (score 0):

I tried upgrading project to .Net 8 but still memory consumption is going too high.